# Angular 8 Multi-domain Multisite

Tags: angular, wordpress, wildcard, firebase-hosting, multisite

I am looking to build a multisite application using angular if possible.  The idea is to allow users to generate a new site with their specified subdomain and point their domain to this subdomain.  Exactly like WordPress's multisite and domain mapping features.

I have gone as far as building a WordPress theme from Angular 8 and used that to achieve my goal but it feels a bit clunky and I'm not a big fan of WordPress's user management system. I am also using firebase for authentication in two other apps so this would be an extension for those apps.

My question(s):
Is this possible using angular?

Could I achieve the desired effect using wp-API and WordPress in headless mode?

Could I simply set up wildcard domains on my host and point all the domains to a single Angular app.  Then use angular wildcard route and firebase to direct and load the correct data for that specific domain?

Or am I missing the mark completely..

Thanks in advance for any remarks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was storing the possible domain names in the DB and used `document.write(document.location)` with a DB query to serve the corresponding content.  That way whenever someone comes to my SPA from example.com they would get the data that is stored under example.com in the DB.  Example2.com gets different data.  The end result was exactly what I was looking for and all I had to do was host the site somewhere where wildcard domains were allowed.  Done!

Comment: Can you further clarify this? How and where is document.write() used? I'm looking to set up subdomains on angular so I'd be able to respond differently to sites with *.mydomain.com.

Comment: @Chano  Sure, I added the document.write() into the app.component.ts file which is loaded every time the app is used.  I had a record for "domains" in my db where I looked to see if that domain was registered in my app, then took the db record id for that domain and served the corresponding content.  It was a lot simpler than I thought it would be.  You can even store html from a WYSIWYG editor and serve custom user-generated html.  Best of  luck, hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

While Firebase Hosting support subdomains, it doesn't support wildcard mappings due to its dependency on letsencrypt.org for certificates.

Comment: So could I approach the problem from a different direction and pass the domain name as a parameter and serve dynamic data based on the incoming domain name?  Say, 1.com would automatically load data from Firebase from ‘sites/1’.  2.com would serve data from’sites/2’ and so on.  Then I could use another host with wildcard domain and point everything to the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by utilizing a plugin of mine, [Xo for Angular](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/).

You could create an Angular App which serves as the theme for your multi-site. The [Xo API](https://angularxo.io/api/controllers) provides a connection for each site to have its own pages and content.

Let me know if you think this could work for you!